# python scraping multiple string with different conditions

Tags: python, regex

My text looks like this:

```
<COREF ID="1">Salman</COREF> <COREF ID="2">Khan</COREF> (pronunciation born <COREF ID="3" REF="2">Abdul Rashid Salim Salman Khan</COREF> on 27 December 1965)[3] is an <COREF ID="14">Indian</COREF> film <COREF ID="15">actor</COREF>, <COREF ID="17">producer</COREF>, television <COREF ID="19">presenter</COREF>, and <COREF ID="20">philanthropist</COREF> known for <COREF ID="4" REF="2">his</COREF> Hindi films. <COREF ID="5" REF="2">He</COREF> is the <COREF ID="21">son</COREF> of <COREF ID="16" REF="15">actor</COREF> and screenwriter Salim <COREF ID="6" REF="2">Khan</COREF>. <COREF ID="7" REF="2">Khan</COREF> began <COREF ID="8" REF="2">his</COREF> acting career with <COREF ID="22">Biwi Ho</COREF> To <COREF ID="24">Aisi</COREF> but <COREF ID="18" REF="17">it</COREF> was <COREF ID="9" REF="2">his</COREF> second film <COREF ID="25">Maine Pyar</COREF> <COREF ID="26">Kiya</COREF>(1989), in which <COREF ID="10" REF="2">he</COREF> acted in a lead role, that garnered <COREF ID="11" REF="2">him</COREF> the Filmfare Award for Best Male Debut. <COREF ID="12" REF="2">Khan</COREF> has starred in several commercially successful films, such as <COREF ID="28">Saajan</COREF> (1991), <COREF ID="29">Hum Aapke Hain Koun</COREF>..! (1994), <COREF ID="30">Karan Arjun</COREF> (1995),<COREF ID="31">Judwaa</COREF> (1997), <COREF ID="32">Pyar</COREF> <COREF ID="27" REF="26">Kiya</COREF> To Darna <COREF ID="33">Kya</COREF> (1998), <COREF ID="23" REF="22">Biwi</COREF> No.1 (1999), and Hum Saath <COREF ID="34">Saath Hain</COREF> (1999), having appeared in the highest grossing film nine separate years during <COREF ID="13" REF="2">his</COREF> career, a record that remains unbroken.[4]
```

What I want to do is

1. Getting each ID with it's string
2. Getting only those id which has `REF`. Result should give `ID` string and `REF` string. If we have `ID` and `REF` num then we can collect the string from result 1 using `map` data structure

I tried in this way:

```
def doit(text):      
  import re
  matches=re.findall(r'\>(.+?)\<',text)
  # matches is now ['String 1', 'String 2', 'String3']
  return ",".join(matches)
print doit(string)
```

which results all strings individually

Now to scrap each ID I did in this way:

```
def doit(text):      
    import re
    #matches = re.findall((?<="ID=")(.*)(?=""))
    matches = re.findall(r'ID=\"(\d+)', text)
    return ",".join(matches)

print doit(string)
```

To scrap content between `ID="` and `"` i.e. ID number but it gives error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What wrong I am doing. Any better alternative?

**UPDATE:**

```
string = "<COREF ID="1">Salman</COREF> <COREF ID="2">Khan</COREF> (pronunciation born <COREF ID="3" REF="2">Abdul Rashid Salim Salman Khan</COREF> on 27 December 1965)[3] is an <COREF ID="14">Indian</COREF> film <COREF ID="15">actor</COREF>, <COREF ID="17">producer</COREF>, television <COREF ID="19">presenter</COREF>, and <COREF ID="20">philanthropist</COREF> known for <COREF ID="4" REF="2">his</COREF> Hindi films. <COREF ID="5" REF="2">He</COREF> is the <COREF ID="21">son</COREF> of <COREF ID="16" REF="15">actor</COREF> and screenwriter Salim <COREF ID="6" REF="2">Khan</COREF>. <COREF ID="7" REF="2">Khan</COREF> began <COREF ID="8" REF="2">his</COREF>"

def doit(text):      
    import re
    #matches = re.findall((?<="ID=")(.*)(?=""))
    matches = re.findall(r'ID=\"(\d+)', text)
    return ",".join(matches)

print doit(string)
```

Comment: You've forgot an opening quote. Also, obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113586

Comment: @wRAR: Is this what you mean`re.findall((?<="ID=")(.*)(?=""))`

Comment: Don't you see that you are not passing a string to `findall`?

Comment: @wRar: it was older code.  please check latest one

Comment: You need to describe the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ID and they are all numeric, try this:

> ```
> re.findall(r'ID=\"(\d+)', text)
> ```

**d+** will only capture numbers.

Comment: thanks dear, but it gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Oh I found the issue, enclosing string with `" "` gives error. Just replaced it with ` ' ' ` now it works

Comment: well is it possible to print `ID : string` in this way?

Comment: Yes, try: [x.replace('=',': ') for x in re.findall(r'ID=\"\d+\"', text)]